# Angular authguard firebase id checking

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I´m trying to make a 404 authguard check. If the id doesn't exist in the database you'll be redirected to a 404 route.

But for some reason the conditional inside the snapshot is never loaded and the authguard automatically redirects you to the home route.

Here's the code:

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
  this.route.params.map(key=>{
    return this.af.database.object('heroes/'+key).first().subscribe(snap => {
      if(snap){
        console.log(true);
        return true;
      }
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the `return this.af.database.list` inside the `map` function?

Comment: Already tried, but the if doesn't work and always returns false.

Comment: Updated the thread with my current problem...

Comment: Add more files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I was using this.route (had 2 routes) instead of just accesing the parameter to get the key.
Also I was using subscribe instead of map (although I don't really understand the difference between map and subscribe in this case) but for some reason accessing the snap with subscribe and returning true didn't work.

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
  return this.af.database.object('heroes/'+route.params.key).map(snap => {
    if(snap.name){
      return true;
    }
      this.router.navigate(['404']);
      return false;
  }).first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `map()` with `params`, `params` is not an array nor an Observable, but an object. You can use `map()` with an `ActivatedRoute`, because it returns an Observable, but a snapshot will return fixed values, not a stream. Also, note that you are using `this.route` instead of `route`. If it isn't throwing an error, probably you have another `route` in the guard.

Probably you can have what you need with a `ParamMap`. If you know the key, you can just have it using `route.paramMap.get('yourkey')`. If you want to iterate all the params in the request, you can have them as array using:

```
route.paramMap.keys.map(key => { ... });
```